# C#: Замена Task.WhenAll

Tags: c#, многопоточность, async-await

Стоит задача избавить от `Task.WhenAll`

Правильно ли логически будет заменить:

```
await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

на

```
    await task1.ConfigureAwait(false);
    await task2.ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Равноценная ли замена?

Спасибо

P.S.
Причины, по которой стоит задача избавиться от `WhenAll` мне не известна.

UPD

Метод

```
    protected override async Task ExecuteInnerAsync(string ids)
            {
                var deleteCommandTask = DeleteCommandCollection(ids);
                var deleteContentTask = DeleteContentCollection(ids);

//стало
                await deleteCommandTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
                await deleteContentTask.ConfigureAwait(false);

//было
                //await Task.WhenAll(deleteCommandTask, deleteContentTask).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
```

Comment: Да. Равноценная.

Comment: @vitidev А не будет ли в этом случае последовательно ожидаться окончание task1 и только потом уже запустится и будет ожидаться task2, а не параллельно будут обе работать, как через Task.WhenAll?

Comment: Не равноценна. WhenAll не запускает таски последоавтельно, ожидая окончание каждой предыдущей. В такой интерпретации в WhenAll нет смысла. @CrazyElf именно так по приведенному коду и будет.

Comment: Равноценна. WhenAll никаких тасков **не запускает**, а только ожидает окончания. Работать они будут параллельно в обоих случаях

Comment: Но разница есть. Если у вас первая таска делается 1 минуту, а на второй через 5 секунд вылетит Exception, то в случае с WhenAll уже через 5 секунд сработает await Task.WhenAll, а в случае последовательных await сначала пройдет минута до того, как выполнение доберется до второго await c искчючением (которое будет сразу же, а не будет еще ждать 5 секунд)

Comment: @vitidev в WhenAll таски будут работать параллельно, в приведенной "замене" они будут работать последовательно.

Comment: Мне кажется, или здесь говорят, что `WhenAll` или `await` запускают таски? Простите, но я уже целые 2 недели знаком с асинхронным программированием, и точно знаю, что нет. Замена не равноценна технически и могут быть нюансы с исключениями, но совершенно равноценна логически.

Comment: Кстати, так как после последнего `await` нет кода, эффекта от `ConfigureAwait(false)` не будет, можно было не нагромождать. Вообще бездумное и повсеместное втыкание ConfigureAwait - плохая практика. В большинстве случаев толку от него никакого.

Comment: @Dzianis Karpuk  Да не будет никакого последовательно. Будьте внимательнее. В приведенном коде обе таски стартовали выше первого await.

Comment: @aepot "ConfigureAwait - плохая практика" - как раз это хорошая практика. Другое дело, что это сильно загромождает код и было глупостью выбрать по дефолту именно ConfigureAwait(true), но это одно из многих неправильных решений в дотнет.

Comment: @vitidev, почему неправильных? Многие бы удивлялись, почему интерфейсозависимые штуки не работают в асинхронном коде. Для значения по умолчанию безопасное решение - вполне ок, как мне кажется. Потом, оно критично только когда речь идет о производительности. А желание добиться производительности - не причина для асинхронности, скорее причина для многопоточности. Вообще ConfigureAwait, кмк, неудачное решение в .net, явно не хватает возможности задать дефолтное поведение машины. Но может, всё еще впереди. :)

Comment: @aepot 1 потому что 99% кода приходится обвешивать ConfigureAwait(false). 2 тикет про "задать дефолтное поведение для сборки" через аттрибут для assembly уже несколько лет висит и толку никакого 3 Они даже не сделали никакой замены ConfigureAwait в виде какого-то короткого варианта. или хотя бы сделали второе ключевое слово. Но обсуждению этого тут не место.